# Why are my replies to a group text appearing multiple times?

Tags: sms

It used to be that when I would reply to a group text, my reply would only show up once. Now all of the sudden when I reply, my reply shows up multiple times. If 5 people are on this group text, my reply shows 5 times. I can't figure out how to stop doing that.